# Using varnish to proxy WordPress (on WPEngine)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, varnish

I have a site served over SSL that sits a server that I manage. I also am using WPEngine to serve up my blog (because I don't want to run the WordPress install myself). That blog page is currently being served without HTTPS.

In order to keep all of my URLs showing in my top level domain, I'm using Varnish to proxy requests to `mytoplevelsite.com/blog` to my WPEngine install.

Without the SSL cert on WPEngine this all works great. However, when I attempt to get this to work with SSL, I get a 301 redirect loop.

My `vcl` looks like this:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080"; # apache is listening here
}

backend blog {
  .host = "wpengine-ip-address";
  .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/blog" && req.http.Host ~ "(.*)mytoplevelsite.com") {
            set req.backend = blog;
            if ((req.url ~ "^/blog/wp-content") || (req.url ~ "^/blog/wp-includes")) {
                    set req.http.host = "mysite.wpengine.com";
                    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/blog", "");
            }
            return(pass);
    }
}
```

In WPEngine I have my SSL installed and have set `mytoplevelsite.com/blog` to be served over HTTPS, but this results in the 301 redirect loop. When I run: `curl -Li https://mytoplevelsite.com/blog` I see this over and over:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:26:07 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://mytoplevelsite.com/blog/
Content-Length: 311
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://mytoplevelsite.com/blog/
X-Type: default
Content-Length: 178
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:26:07 GMT
X-Varnish: 1087407254
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive

... repeat until timeout
```

Any ideas of what I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared SSL (a Wildcard I assume) upload the key and cert files to your `_wpeprivate` folder using sFTP, then get their support to place a copy of the cert on their servers.
(This is the proper way for any subdomain sites hosted on different servers.)

Force the SSL through the my.wpengine.com user portal. `Overview > SSL > Click the SSL and force all to SSL`

Forcing SSL in any other way than that recommended method above will usually cause a redirect loop.